# Why is $\int|Y-f|\Pr(y|x)dy=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=0}|Y_i-f|$

Tags: probability, integration

I am trying to solve
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial f} \int|Y-f|\Pr(y|X=x)dy$$

This is quite complicated so thr solution is to approximate the integral:
$$
\int|Y-f|\Pr(y|x)dy=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=0}|Y_i-f|
$$

I am not aware of that version of the limit form of the integral. How did the right hand resulted? Also, the conditional probability is lost.

Is $\frac{1}{n}$ the differential separation? Furthermore, what happened to the conditional probability?